# Initialize object data members C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Consider the following code:

```
class Game {
private:
  vector<SomeType*> vec;
  OtherType obj;

public:
  Game(char* configuration_file);
};
```

How should one implement the Game constructor considering that both vec and obj are dependent on configuration_file content?

Initialization list is impossible to use since configuration_file has to be parsed before constructing vec and obj.

If i will constrcut vec and obj inside the body of the constructor, than both default constructors for both of them will be called, is there a way to prevent this ?

What is the normal way to do this kind of things ?

Thanks.

Comment: why not copy construct it directly obj = OtherType(parsedData); in the constructors body. if you make the default constructor private, it will not compile

Comment: from my understanding that will cause a call to obj default constructor since all Game data members have to be initialized before entering the body, i would like to save that call.

Comment: yes, before entering the body constructor, all default constructor of objects will be called. john zwick solution is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default-constructing the vector is certainly harmless, so let's assume that default-constructing OtherType is impossible.  Then I'd handle it this way:

```
class Game {
private:
  vector<SomeType*> vec;
  OtherType obj;

  static OtherType load(const char* config_file);

public:
  Game(const char* config_file)
    : obj(load(config_file))
  {
    // populate vec here
  }
};
```

Comment: @Captain_Tiras: That would be one way, or you could just implement `load()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, one has to take a slight detour in order to get where one's going.

First, write a static private function:

```
std::pair<std::vector<SomeType *>, OtherType> Game::parse_config_file(char *configuration_file)
{
  // ...
}
```

This would be a private static function that parses the configuration file into this kind of data.

Now, you can put this jigsaw puzzle together:

```
class Game_config {

protected:

  vector<SomeType*> vec;
  OtherType obj;

  Game_config(const std::pair<std::vector<SomeType *>, OtherType> &);
};

class Game : private Game_config {

    static std::pair<std::vector<SomeType *>, OtherType> Game::parse_config_file(char *configuration_file);

public:
  Game(char* configuration_file) : Game_config(parse_config_file())
  {
  }
};
```

`Game_config`'s constructor should be obvious.

A slight variation of the above would be to have `parse_config_file()` return the `Game_config` superclass, and have `Game`'s constructor copy-construct its superclass. A modern compiler should be able to use RVO, in this use case.